# error Hibernate : referred to by multiple logical column names: [cod_asignatura], [codAsignatura]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Al arrancar spring boot se me muestra una excepcion `org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException` , no llego a entender por que pasa si las anotaciones aparentemente estan bien puestas en cada propiedad

Tabla matricula

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Matricula {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cod_matricula")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "cod_matricula", 
    strategy = "com.proyectomvc.utils.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator", 
    parameters = {
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "3"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "COD_MAT"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d") })
private String codMatricula;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "cod_asignatura")
private List<Asignatura> asignaturas;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "matricula", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Alumno Alumno;

public Matricula() {
}

public Matricula(String codMatricula, List<Asignatura> asignaturas,Alumno alumno) {
    this.codMatricula = codMatricula;
    this.asignaturas = asignaturas;
    this.Alumno = alumno;
}

public Matricula(List<Asignatura> asignaturas, Alumno alumno) {
    this.asignaturas = asignaturas;
    this.Alumno = alumno;
}

public String getCodMatricula() {
    return codMatricula;
}

public void setCodMatricula(String codMatricula) {
    this.codMatricula = codMatricula;
}

public List<Asignatura> getAsignaturas() {
    return asignaturas;
}

public void setAsignaturas(List<Asignatura> asignaturas) {
    this.asignaturas = asignaturas;
}

public Alumno getAlumno() {
    return Alumno;
}

public void setAlumno(Alumno alumno) {
    Alumno = alumno;
}


}
```

Tabla asignatura

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Asignatura {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cod_asignatura")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "cod_asignatura", 
    strategy = "com.proyectomvc.utils.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator", 
    parameters = {
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "3"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "COD_ASIG"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d") })
private String codAsignatura;

@Column(name="nombre")
private String nombre;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "id_profesor")
private Profesor profesor;

public Asignatura() {
}


public Asignatura(String codAsignatura, String nombre, Profesor profesor) {
    this.codAsignatura = codAsignatura;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.profesor = profesor;
}


public Asignatura(String nombre, Profesor profesor) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.profesor = profesor;
}

public String getCodAsignatura() {
    return codAsignatura;
}

public void setCodAsignatura(String codAsignatura) {
    this.codAsignatura = codAsignatura;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}


public Profesor getProfesor() {
    return profesor;
}

public void setProfesor(Profesor profesor) {
    this.profesor = profesor;
}

}
```

La excepcion

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [asignatura] contains physical column name [cod_asignatura] referred to by multiple logical column names: [cod_asignatura], [codAsignatura]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás sería interesante que incluyeras la entidad Asignatura y la estructura de las tablas correspondientes que hay en la base de datos.

Comment: ya los he añadido

Comment: Viendo el esquema de la BD me surge la duda de cómo puede tener una matricula asociada una lista de asignaturas. Para representar esto creo que debería haber una tabla intermedia MATRICULA_X_ASIGNATURA con tres campos: su clave, cod_matricula y cod_asignatura. Tal y como lo tienes estás estableciendo una relación 1:1 y no 1:N

Comment: lo he solucionado añadiendo @Column

Comment: Puedes responder a tu pregunta añadiendo una explicación de porque con esa etiqueta te funciona correctamente.

Comment: ya estaria puesto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadiendo `@Column(name="cod_asignatura")` y `@Column(name="cod_matricula")` se soluciona el problema y cambiado generador id.

Clase asignatura

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cod_asig_seq")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "cod_asig_seq", 
    strategy = "com.proyectomvc.utils.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator", 
    parameters = {
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "3"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "COD_ASIG"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d") })
@Column(name="cod_asignatura")
private String codAsignatura;
```

Clase matricula

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cod_mat_seq")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "cod_mat_seq", 
    strategy = "com.proyectomvc.utils.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator", 
    parameters = {
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "3"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "COD_MAT"),
@Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d") })
@Column(name="cod_matricula")
private String codMatricula;
```

Comment: Y has cambiado el nombre de los generadores de id. Eso de que se llamaran igual que la columna no me daba buenas sensaciones.